# Getting Number of Events in EventLog via Powershell

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-winevent

My goal is to get the amount of EventLog Entries of a specific Log with a small powershell script.
The amount should be converted to a variable.

Now I am at a point that I really dont know how to accomplish this. Can you help?
Maybe there is an Option in Get-WinEvent?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the `-ListLog` parameter will help you get a count.
Here are some examples

**A specific log** (eg: Application)

```
$ApplicationLogsCount = (Get-WinEvent -ListLog Application).RecordCount
```

**All logs**

```
$AllLogs = Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Select LogName,RecordCount
```

**All non-empty logs**

```
$AllNonEmptyLogs = Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Select LogName,RecordCount | Where-Object -Property RecordCount -gt 0
```

**References**

[Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent)